# Kohana 3: Hide part of url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, kohana, kohana-3

I have a problem with hiding part of url in Kohana 3.

There are controlers stored in admin subfolder. 
These controlers power admin panel of site. 
So when I type :

`http://mysite.xyz/admin`

it works ok. I need only admin panel of that kohana project, and I decided to create subdomain `admin`.

So now when I type:

`http://admin.mysite.xyz/admin`

it works ok.
But I want to hide that `admin` part of url and when I will type:

`http://admin.mysite.xyz`

I will not load kohana site, but admin panel.

---

Here is my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

###### Add trailing slash (optional) ######
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php/(.*)$ /$1$2 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond $1 ^(index\.php|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|media)
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?kohana_uri=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?admin.schoener-tauchen.pl$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ admin [L]

RewriteRule ^admin/(.+)$ $1 [L,NC,R]
```

**It doesn't work. It gives 404 error.**

Can someone help, please?

**PS.** Changing Kohana routing is unfortunately very complicated in this case. Htaccess changes seems to be easier.

---

**EDIT**

bootstrap.php route:

```
Route::set('admin', 'admin(/<controller>(,<action>(,<id>)(,<id2>)(,<id3>)))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'directory' => 'admin',
        'controller' => 'home',
        'action'     => 'index',
));

Route::set('default', '(<controller>(,<action>(,<id>)))', array('controller'=>'\w+','controller'=>'\w+', 'action'=>'\w+', 'param' => '.+'))
    ->defaults(array(
        'directory' => 'admin',
        'controller' => 'home',
        'action'     => 'index',
));
```

Comment: Update your default route to use Admin controller.

Comment: How can I do it? I'm not kohana programmer and I didn't create that website. Should I attach some code?

Comment: check bootstrap.php and if you can past Route::set('default' code here i can help.

Comment: move the default route before admin route..

Comment: You can read this page for reference as well. https://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/routing

Comment: I have already read it, but any ideas, which I'm trying don't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I solved it by the hack in .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^admin/(.+)$ $1 [L,NC,R]
```

In view's files and controllers there are links, URLs which contain that `admin`. Htaccess force it to skip that `admin` part.

Answer (score 0):

Use bootstrap.php

```
$is_admin = preg_match('/^admin\.schoener-tauchen\.pl$/', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
Route::set('default', '(<action>(/<id>))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => $is_admin ? 'admin' : 'index',
        'action'     => 'index',
));
```

And remove from .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?admin.schoener-tauchen.pl$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ admin [L]

RewriteRule ^admin/(.+)$ $1 [L,NC,R]
```

Comment: I get error: `ReflectionException [ -1 ]: Class controller_admin does not exist`.

In bootstrap.php I have a rule:

`Route::set('admin', 'admin(/<controller>(,<action>(,<id>)(,<id2>)(,<id3>)))')
 ->defaults(array(
  'directory' => 'admin',
  'controller' => 'home',
  'action'     => 'index',
));`

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest this solution, comment out both routes in bootstrap and replace them with this.

```
Kohana::init ( array (
        'base_url' => '/'
));

Route::set('default', '(<controller>(,<action>(,<id>)(,<id2>)(,<id3>)))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'directory' => 'admin',
        'controller' => 'home',
        'action'     => 'index',
));
```

Here is [Kohana official route guide](https://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/routing)

Comment: Now, when I type `admin.site.xyz`, that redirect to `admin.site.xyz//admin/login/` (where login is controller) and give kohana error: Unable to find a route to match the URI: admin/logowanie.

Comment: I suppose that problem is, becouse controllers and views have linking (redirects, links, form action reload targets) to url in scheme: `base_url/admin/controller/model`. For example, when after above change I manualy type admin.site.xyz/login page load ok, but when I click submit button, there is still same error.

Comment: That depends how URL for form action is generated. in Bootstrap.php you can update Kohana::init ( array (
  'base_url' => '/'));  it will help if URL is not hardcoded